# lwjgl java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, lwjgl

The program successfully extracts the jars to the folder `/home/ty/gopro2027game/lib/jars/` and the natives to `/home/ty/gopro2027game/lib/jars/`. The program also, first thing besides copying the files, runs this:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", Game.gameFolder+"/lib/jars");
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", 
new File(Game.gameFolder+"/lib/natives").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath"));
```

The println's show the right folder for the files too. But i get this error when ran (this is all after exporting the program):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
at com.gopro2027.lwjgl.Start.Solo(Start.java:144)
at com.gopro2027.lwjgl.Start.main(Start.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 2 more
```

I do not know how this is happening and i don't want to go back to jarmatey. Thanks- Tyler

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` practically always means that you are missing a jar file in your classpath. Make sure that you include all the necessary jars in your classpath.

Comment: That looks like the error you get when you forget to set the native library for LWJGL. There are individual libraries you have to set for win/lin/mac.

Comment: all of the natives for win linux and mac are in that folder

Comment: @TylerSonger I have this very problem - did you found a solution? If so, could you, please, post it here?